# An option must be a rule or a list of rules - error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I want to plot the following code, in 1D.
However, code displayed below is not being plotted; no results or errors are displayed

```
Plot[((16*10^-12)/(4*π*8.854188*Sqrt[4*π*0.125*10^6*t])*(Sum[Integrate[((\[Minus]1)^m E^(\[Minus](x\[Minus]200m-99.5)^2/4*0.125*10^6*t))/(99.5-x)^2,{x,0,100}],{m,\[Minus]∞,+∞}]+Sum[Integrate[((\[Minus]1)^m E^(\[Minus](x\[Minus]200m+99.5)^2/4*0.125*10^6*t))/(99.5-x)^2,{x,0,100}],{m,\[Minus]∞,+∞}])),{t,0,100},PlotRange->All]
```

code doesn't run.
Could you please help?
I tried to use Plot instead of Plot3D as i now used just the range of {t,0,100}

thanks in advance

Comment: Please copy your code into the post - do not post screenshots.

Comment: You are using { } in your formula ... why? These are for lists and related constructs - use () if you mean to delimit your sub-expressions with parentheses. Your error is because you have two ranges `{t,0,100}` and what looks like {`x',0,100}`. But `Plot` only supports one range. Do you want `Plot3D` instead?

Comment: thanks @flinty,
i tried to run the below code in screenshot attached in initial post (code too long to add it here as a comment):

but i get no result at all

Comment: Can you paste the code into the question? Again, do not post screenshots. I do not want to type out everything in that Plot command myself.

Comment: @flinty sorry about that, code added now. thanks!

Comment: Some problems: 1. You are using e but you should use E to mean Euler's number. 2. You are using x' which means `Derivative[1][x]` - better to just call this x. 3. You should consider using Sum and Integrate rather than the presentational forms of the sums and integrals which is why your code has loads of SuperscriptBox stuff in it.

Comment: will try to do so, but x' is not the derivative of x, it's just another variable.

Comment: Another problem: you have `m = +∞` and `m = -∞` in your sums. This is assigning those infinities to your m permanently. If you continue using the presentational sum (see 3. above) then only the bottom one should have `m = -∞` while the top should just be +∞ on its own.

Comment: _but x' is not the derivative of x_ Yes which is why you should not write x' because it turns it into a `Derivative[1][x]`.

Comment: i changed x' - you're right,
i also changed the presentational forms (updated code in question)

Comment: Your integrals do not converge on {0,100} because this includes the number 99.5, and (99.5-99.5)^2 is zero on the denominator.

Comment: you're right, but it's not running even for {x,0,90} for example

Comment: The infinite sums are very slow and Plot has to run these over a lot of points. Perhaps you can find a way to put your expression in a different form, or pre-calculate the sums / integrals in a closed form that evaluates more efficiently.